# When firing mousedown event on Material UI Select in jest tests I always get "anchorEl" warning

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

Jest test code:

```
import { fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react"
// some code
fireEvent.mouseDown(container.querySelector("#section")!)
```

React component under test code:

```
import { Select } from "@material-ui/core"
// some code
<Select id="section"> // some props omitted
  <MenuItem>...</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>...</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

The code does work, the "mousedown" event causes the desired effect ("click" event does not, but that's beside the point)

But every time it runs, I see this warning in the output:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Material-UI: The `anchorEl` prop provided
> to the component is invalid.
> The anchor element should be part of the document layout.
> Make sure the element is present in the document or that it's not display none.

Is there any way to fix that warning?

Comment: I just tried your simple example in a `create-react-app` app, and I don't get the warning when the test passes.

Comment: @RomanMkrtchian I think I found the error. I had the environment variable NODE_ENV set to "Test" in package.json "scripts:test" attribute (with a capital T, NODE_ENV=Test). That's definitely a mistake. As soon as I unset it, the warnings went away.

Answer (score 1):

In my package.json, sctipts -> test, I had "NODE_ENV=Test" preceding the jest command. That can't be right, it should have been "test", and it's unnecessary anyway.

I removed "NODE_ENV=Test" and the issue went away.